# MySQL call a stored procedure every x minutes

Tags: sql, mysql, events, stored-procedures, session

Is there a way in MySQL to call a stored procedure from within SQL every x minutes?

I want to use this in a session-environment, where the database keeps track of all the sessions and automatically deletes sessions older than x minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MySQL Events](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html), it was introduced in version 5.1.